# Trouble installing opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am having trouble installing opencart. This is on my personal laptop (as a test server) running the usual LAMP stack. I have PHP 7.3 installed and I am getting this strange error upon accessing the webroot (which runs the installer). `PH7.3+ Required`. I am assuming it means PHP 7.3+, which I have installed:

```
PHP 7.3.20-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2020 16:34:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.20, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.20-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
root@gardenia:/home/dperygin# sudo systemctl restart apache2
root@gardenia:/home/dperygin# php -v
PHP 7.3.20-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2020 16:34:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.20, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.20-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Thanks for any assistance.
Donna

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: The error is: PH7.3+ Required

Comment: Opencart version?

Comment: The php version you are showing is from the CLI. I wonder if your LAMP is using a different version. Maybe use phpinfo() in a script and check what version that returns from the localhost url?

Comment: Thanks, Mark. That is the problem.

Comment: Formatted error message so it stands out

Comment: I am facing the same problem. How I can use phpinfo() AND where I should use it?

Comment: You need to create a phpinfo() script and access it from a browser. Take this script. Save it to a file info.php and access it from your browser. 

<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL

phpinfo();


?>

Comment: Also, I got so many installation errors with opencart this time around, I switched to Word Press. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

**These plugins must be working for the OpenStore script to function properly.**

Web Server - Apache recommended
PHP 7.3 -

#### Note: OpenCart 3.0.3.6 is not fully compatible with PHP 7.4

MySQL - MySQLi is highly recommended

PHP requirements

The required PHP requirements are:

1. roll
2. zoom
3. Zleep
4. GD Library
5. MacCrypt
6. MBStrings

The PHP requirements described in the hacker are most often used in most hosting services. There should be another contact, provided that there is another situation. And in the event that it is not activated.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that the server where the open cart is deployed doesnot comply with the required PHP version.You need to upgrade the PHP version to 7.3.0+

```
// Check Version
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '7.3.0', '<') == true) {
exit('PH7.3+ Required');
```

}

Above code can be found in startup.php file under system folder in opencart (3.0.3.7) which is causing the error message to display.

To verify php version , add the below file in server and access it in the browser.

## main.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP version check</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   echo phpinfo();
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

You should see the details in browser.

> https://<< yourdomain >>/main.php

[image: php version in browser]